I'm having trouble populating and displaying ASP:Treeview - the tree won't display
<asp:TreeView ID="tvReportNavigation" runat="server" AutoGenerateDataBindings="False" Visible="true">
    <LevelStyles>
        <asp:TreeNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" 
             ImageUrl='<%$ Code: GetAppImageUrl("Folder.gif") %>' />
        <asp:TreeNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" Font-Bold="True" 
             ImageUrl='<%$ Code: GetAppImageUrl("Folder.gif") %>' />
    </LevelStyles>
    <HoverNodeStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="Yellow" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <DataBindings>               
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Content" />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Folder" TextField="Name" ValueField="RegistryID" />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="VirtualFolder" TextField="Name" ValueField="Name" />
    </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>

I tried the following function to display the tree:
Public Function LoadReportNavigation(ByVal contextAppUser As AppUser) As Boolean

    Dim wasSuccessful As Boolean = False

    ClearReportFileListing()

    If Not IsNothing(contextAppUser) Then

        Dim folderNotFound As Boolean = False
        Dim permissionDenied As Boolean = False

        ' For Trainers, show navigation "content type" choices and the Trainer-only document folder.
        pnlReportNavSelection.Visible = CanSeeReportNavSelectionPanel(contextAppUser)
        tvTrainerDocs.Visible = (contextAppUser.UserType = AppUser.AppUserType.Trainer)
        pnlReportNavSelection.Visible = True
        tvTrainerDocs.Visible = True
        pnlReportNav.Visible = True
        tvReportNavigation.Visible = True
        _selectedSiteId = CInt(ddlContext_Site.SelectedValue)
        Try
            Dim regEntity As RegistryEntity = AppUserController.GetRegEntityForUserContext(contextAppUser, _selectedUtcId, _selectedSiteId)
            Dim xmldsData As XmlDataSource = ListFolderContents(contextAppUser,
                                                                regEntity,
                                                                GetRequestedContentType(contextAppUser),
                                                                folderNotFound,
                                                                permissionDenied,
                                                                wasSuccessful)

            ToggleVisibleStatus(pnlReportNav, True)

            With tvReportNavigation

                .DataBindings(0).Value = regEntity.RegistryId + TREENODE_ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR + CStr(regEntity.RegistryType)
                .DataBindings(0).Text = regEntity.RegistryName
                '  SelectByWindowsIdentity.DataBindings(0).Text = regEntity.RegistryName

                If folderNotFound Then
                    ToggleFileListDisplay(False, regEntity.RegistryName)
                ElseIf permissionDenied Then
                    ShowFileListPermissionDenied()
                ElseIf wasSuccessful Then
                    Dim entity As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
                    Dim newTreeNode As TreeNode
                    ' Folders for child entities:
                    For Each entity In GetEntityIdsAndNames(xmldsData,
                                                    "Content",
                                                    "Folder",
                                                    "RegistryID",
                                                    "Name",
                                                    "RegistryType",
                                                    TREENODE_ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR)
                        newTreeNode = New TreeNode(entity.Value, entity.Key, GetAppImageUrl(IMAGE_FILENAME_FOLDER))
                        'If node IsNot Nothing Then
                        'If node IsNot Nothing Then

                        tvReportNavigation.Nodes.Add(newTreeNode)

                        'End If
                    Next

                    Dim virtualEntity As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
                    ' Virtual folders:
                    For Each virtualEntity In GetEntityIdsAndNames(xmldsData,
                                                               "Content",
                                                               "VirtualFolder",
                                                               "Name",
                                                               "Name",
                                                               "",
                                                               TREENODE_ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR)
                        Dim VnewTreeNode = New TreeNode(virtualEntity.Value, CStr(virtualEntity.Key), GetAppImageUrl(IMAGE_FILENAME_FOLDER))
                        'If node IsNot Nothing Then
                        tvReportNavigation.Nodes.Add(VnewTreeNode)
                        'End If
                    Next
                    'If node IsNot Nothing Then
                    tvReportNavigation.ExpandAll()
                    'End If
                    'tvReportNavigation.Nodes.Clear()
                    'Dim entity As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
                    'Dim newTreeNode As TreeNode
                    ' Folders for child entities
                    'For Each entity In GetEntityIdsAndNames(xmldsData,
                    '                                        "Content",
                    '                                                "Folder",
                    '                                                "RegistryID",
                    '                                                "Name",
                    '                                               "RegistryType",
                    ' TREENODE_ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR)
                    'newTreeNode = New TreeNode(entity.Value, entity.Key, GetAppImageUrl(IMAGE_FILENAME_FOLDER))
                    ' tvReportNavigation.Nodes.Add(newTreeNode)
                    'newTreeNode.ChildNodes.Add(newTreeNode)
                    'Next

                    'Dim virtualEntity As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
                    'Virtual folders
                    'For Each virtualEntity In GetEntityIdsAndNames(xmldsData,
                    '                                              "Content",
                    '                                                      "VirtualFolder",
                    '                                                      "Name",
                    '                                                      "Name",
                    '                                                     "",
                    'TREENODE_ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR)
                    'newTreeNode = New TreeNode(virtualEntity.Value, CStr(virtualEntity.Key), GetAppImageUrl(IMAGE_FILENAME_FOLDER))
                    'tvReportNavigation.Nodes.Add(newTreeNode)
                    'Next
                    'tvReportNavigation.Nodes(0).Select()
                    'LoadNodeNavigation(_contextAppUser, regEntity, tvReportNavigation.SelectedNode)
                    'tvReportNavigation.ExpandAll()
                    'tvReportNavigation = tvReportNavigation
                    'tvReportNavigation = tvReportNavigation
                    'tvReportNavigation.DataSource = xmldsData
                    '.Nodes(0).Select()
                    'LoadNodeNavigation(_contextAppUser, GetSelectedRegEntity(Nothing), tvReportNavigation.SelectedNode)
                    'tvReportNavigation.DataBind()
                    'tvReportNavigation.Nodes(0).Select()
                    'tvReportNavigation.DataSource = xmldsData
                    'tvReportNavigation.DataBind()
                    'tvReportNavigation.Nodes(0).Select()
                    'Dim newNode As TreeNode
                    'newNode = New TreeNode("FirstNode")
                    'tvReportNavigation.Nodes.Add(newNode)
                    'tvReportNavigation.Nodes.Add(newNode)
                    'tvReportNavigation.Nodes.Add(newNode)
                    'tvReportNavigation = tvReportNavigation
                    'tvReportNavigation = tvReportNavigation
                    'tvReportNavigation.ExpandAll()
                    'tvReportNavigation.Visible = True
                Else
                    DisplayMessage(mdMessageDisplay, MessageSeverityLevel.Err, MESSAGE_ERROR_RETRIEVING_DATA_NAVIGATION + MESSAGE_GENERIC_ERROR_SUFFIX)
                    LogEvent(EventLogEntryType.Error, (New StackFrame).GetMethod(), "wasSuccessful returned False, but no exception thrown")
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            HandleException(ex, (New StackFrame).GetMethod(), mdMessageDisplay, "", MESSAGE_GENERIC_ERROR)
        End Try

    End If

    Return wasSuccessful

End Function

However, the tree does not get populated or displayed.
Does anyone have any ideas?
